# Laravel mysql union of multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, union

I have **multiple *identical* mysql database tables**. 
What I need is a **raw sql** or **Laravel schema** to get the **Union** of all the tables in the database except the one's that are not identical.

I already tried the following code

```
$multipleUnion = DB::table('teble_1')->union(DB::table('teble_2')->union(DB::table('teble_3')))->get();
```

but I got this error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union (select * from `table_3`))' at line 1 (SQL: (select * from `table_1`) union ((select * from `table_2`) union (select * from `table_3`)))

I don't want to query like

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 UNION SELECT * FROM table_2 UNION SELECT * FROM table_3
```

Because the number of tables can increase as the time goes. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$multipleUnion = DB::table('teble_1')->union(DB::table('teble_2'))
    ->union(DB::table('teble_3'))->get();
```

Creating a query from an array of table names:

```
$query = DB::table($tables[0]);
foreach(array_slice($tables, 1) as $table) {
    $query->union(DB::table($table));
}
$multipleUnion = $query->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering...
It worked!!!
But is there anyway I can get the union of all tables without hardcoding the table names.
The error causing laravel query I mentioned above, came out of recursion.

Comment: Do you mean from an array of table names?

Comment: Thank you so much.
That answer saved lot of my work from being changed
That's exactly what I needed.